# CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, cmtime

Want to compare `CMTime` and based on that I am performing loop. Converting `ObjectiveC` to `Swift`, I can't found suitable method for `CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE`.

```
CMTime oneSecond = CMTimeMake( 1, 1 );
CMTime oneSecondAgo = CMTimeSubtract( timestamp, oneSecond );

while( CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE( [_previousSecondTimestamps[0] CMTimeValue], <, oneSecondAgo ) ) {
    [_previousSecondTimestamps removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Has anybody face this similar issue in any version of `Swift`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CMTime` is imported as a `Comparable` type in Swift 3, so, you have no need to use `CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE`.

Assuming `_previousSecondTimestamps` is of type `[CMTime]` (*1), you can write something like this in Swift 3:

```
    let oneSecond = CMTime(seconds: 1.0, preferredTimescale: 1)
    let oneSecondAgo = timestamp - oneSecond

    while !_previousSecondTimestamps.isEmpty && _previousSecondTimestamps[0] < oneSecondAgo {
        _previousSecondTimestamps.remove(at: 0)
    }
```

*1 In Swift, you can declare an Array of `CMTime` directly, you have no need to use `NSMutableArray` containing `NSValue`.

Comment: Thanks! Although I have found an another solution too!